# gcloud deploy error: Image with tag google/docker-registry was not found

Tags: google-app-engine

I'm trying to deploy this project https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/appengine-nodejs-quickstart by using this command

```
gcloud --project poised-graph-758 preview app deploy --server preview.appengine.google.com .
```

but i get this error:

```
Updating module [default] from file [/Users/kannix/Desktop/tmp/appengine-nodejs-quickstart/app.yaml]
11:36 PM Host: preview.appengine.google.com
{bucket: vm-containers.poised-graph-758.appspot.com, path: /containers}

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/kannix/google-cloud-sdk/./lib/googlecloudsdk/gcloud/gcloud.py", line 153, in <module>
    main()
  File "/Users/kannix/google-cloud-sdk/./lib/googlecloudsdk/gcloud/gcloud.py", line 149, in main
    _cli.Execute()
  File "/Users/kannix/google-cloud-sdk/./lib/googlecloudsdk/calliope/cli.py", line 381, in Execute
    post_run_hooks=self.__post_run_hooks, kwargs=kwargs)
  File "/Users/kannix/google-cloud-sdk/./lib/googlecloudsdk/calliope/frontend.py", line 274, in _Execute
    pre_run_hooks=pre_run_hooks, post_run_hooks=post_run_hooks)
  File "/Users/kannix/google-cloud-sdk/./lib/googlecloudsdk/calliope/backend.py", line 887, in Run
    result = command_instance.Run(args)
  File "/Users/kannix/google-cloud-sdk/./lib/googlecloudsdk/calliope/exceptions.py", line 78, in TryFunc
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/kannix/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/appengine/app_commands/deploy.py", line 154, in Run
    self.__Run(args, project, deployables)
  File "/Users/kannix/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/appengine/app_commands/deploy.py", line 207, in __Run
    info.runtime, path, bucket)
  File "/Users/kannix/google-cloud-sdk/./lib/googlecloudsdk/appengine/lib/images/push.py", line 134, in BuildAndPushDockerImage
    boto_path=config.BOTO_PATH)) as r:
  File "/Users/kannix/google-cloud-sdk/./lib/googlecloudsdk/appengine/lib/images/registry.py", line 148, in __enter__
    self.Start()
  File "/Users/kannix/google-cloud-sdk/./lib/googlecloudsdk/appengine/lib/images/registry.py", line 97, in Start
    self._registry.Start()
  File "/Users/kannix/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/docker/containers.py", line 480, in Start
    self._image.Build()
  File "/Users/kannix/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/docker/containers.py", line 309, in Build
    raise ImageError('Image with tag %s was not found' % self.tag)
google.appengine.tools.docker.containers.ImageError: Image with tag google/docker-registry was not found
```

I tried to omit the `--server preview.appengine.google.com` parameter but it results in the same error

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to pull the google/docker-registry image to resolve this error:

```
docker pull google/docker-registry
```

*Note*: if you receive the following error when trying to redeploy:

```
docker.docker.errors.APIError: 500 Server Error: Internal Server Error ("Invalid registry endpoint https://192.168.59.103:49153/v1/: Get https://192.168.59.103:49153/v1/_ping: EOF. If this private registry supports only HTTP or HTTPS with an unknown CA certificate, please add `--insecure-registry 192.168.59.103:49153` to the daemon's arguments. In the case of HTTPS, if you have access to the registry's CA certificate, no need for the flag; simply place the CA certificate at /etc/docker/certs.d/192.168.59.103:49153/ca.crt")
```

Ensure that your docker daemon has been setup with the 'insecure registry' option (**you will need to re-pull the google/docker-registry after the following steps**) . You can do this with the following, (which was an answer on https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/8887):

```
$ boot2docker delete #removes old image
$ rm -f ~/.ssh/id_boot2docker* # remove old keys
$ boot2docker init #generates new keys, cert
$ boot2docker up
$ boot2docker ssh
$ # add EXTRA_ARGS="--insecure-registry <YOUR INSECURE HOST>" 
$ # to /var/lib/boot2docker/profile
$ sudo /etc/init.d/docker restart
```

Comment: This does not answer the original question. Maybe more appropriate as a comment to the question, providing more information on the issue.

Comment: I updated the entry, with the resolution to the insecure registry issue as well. Thanks.

Comment: I followed the steps but now i get this error :(
2014/11/10 00:35:26 Get https://192.168.59.103:2375/v1.15/version: tls: oversized record received with length 20527

Comment: sorry, I don't hit that error. Maybe make that a top level question and see if someone has an answer. Only thing I can say is try to make sure everything is updated, gcloud tools, docker image, etc.

Comment: After adding this EXTRA_ARGS="--insecure-registry 192.168.59.103:49153 --insecure-registry 192.168.59.103:49154" to my /var/lib/boot2docker/profile file it seems to work. Thx for your help :)

Comment: i don't have that `/var/lib/boot2docker/profile` I tried to add it but the error is still there. What other things can I try?

Comment: @yusufm If I do what you wrote, when I exit and go to my machine console and do a `docker ps` it returns `Cannot connect to the Docker daemon. Is 'docker -d' running on this host?` Why?

Answer (score 3):

Try running this first:

```
gcloud preview app setup-managed-vms
```

Also make sure you're running Docker 1.3.0, not 1.3.1.

Docker 1.4.0 also doesn't work at this moment.

Comment: Docker 1.3.2 fixed the problem that 1.3.1 had

Answer (score 0):

Deploying with `--server preview.appengine.google.com` did it for me.