# DockerDaemonConnectionError when setting Google Cloud Managed VM in Ubuntu

Tags: python, google-compute-engine, google-cloud-platform

I'm trying to install Google Cloud Managed VM in Ubuntu according to this manuals: [[1]](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/managed-vms/), [[2]](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/managed-vms/sdk)

I've installed Docker following the [Docker installation guide](https://docs.docker.com/installation/ubuntulinux/).

Running Docker with: `sudo docker -H tcp://127.0.0.1:2376 -d`

I've created certificate keys according to the [HTTPS Docker guide](http://docs.docker.com/articles/https/).

My environments variables:

- DOCKER_HOST=tcp://:2376
- DOCKER_TLS_VERIFY=1
- DOCKER_CERT_PATH=/home/eyalev/ca

When I run `gcloud preview app setup-managed-vms`

I get an error:

https://gist.github.com/eyalev/aab86463bc63f4319d5c

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/eyalev/Software/google-cloud-sdk/./lib/googlecloudsdk/gcloud/gcloud.py",
 line 153, in <module> main()   File "/home/eyalev/Software/google-cloud-sdk/./lib/googlecloudsdk/gcloud/gcloud.py",
 line 149, in main _cli.Execute()   File "/home/eyalev/Software/google-cloud-sdk/./lib/googlecloudsdk/calliope/cli.py",
 line 381, in Execute post_run_hooks=self.__post_run_hooks, kwargs=kwargs)   File "/home/eyalev/Software/google-cloud-sdk/./lib/googlecloudsdk/calliope/frontend.py",
 line 274, in _Execute pre_run_hooks=pre_run_hooks, post_run_hooks=post_run_hooks)   File "/home/eyalev/Software/google-cloud-sdk/./lib/googlecloudsdk/calliope/backend.py",
 line 887, in Run result = command_instance.Run(args)   File "/home/eyalev/Software/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/appengine/app_commands/setup_managed_vms.py",
 line 37, in Run setup_registry.SetupRegistry()   File "/home/eyalev/Software/google-cloud-sdk/./lib/googlecloudsdk/appengine/lib/images/setup_registry.py",
 line 32, in SetupRegistry timeout=config.DOCKER_D_REQUEST_TIMEOUT)   File "/home/eyalev/Software/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/docker/containers.py",
 line 663, in NewDockerClient 'Couldn\'t connect to the docker daemon using the specified ' google.appengine.tools.docker.containers.DockerDaemonConnectionError:

Couldn't connect to the docker daemon using the specified environment
variables. Please check the environment variables DOCKER_HOST,
DOCKER_CERT_PATH and DOCKER_TLS_VERIFY are set correctly. If you are
using boot2docker, make sure you have run "$(boot2docker shellinit)"
```

Is there something I'm missing?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I finally got `gcloud preview app setup-managed-vms` to work on ubuntu. Here's what I had to do:

1. get docker 1.3.0, not 1.3.1. `sudo apt-get install docker.io` installed and old version of docker on my machine, so I had to remove that first. But `curl -sSL https://get.docker.com/ubuntu/ | sudo sh` installs version 1.3.1, which also doesn't work. I replayed every line in the script at `https://get.docker.com/ubuntu/` but I had to change the last line `apt-get install -y lxc-docker` to `apt-get install -y lxc-docker-1.3.0` The official docs mention that app engine doesn't work with boot2docker 1.3.1, but I think they meant that it doesn't work with docker 1.3.1.
2. I couldn't get 127.0.0.1 to work as my host name. I had to use `localhost` when creating the ca and server certificates.
3. I had to export `DOCKER_HOST=tcp://localhost:2376` (note the use of localhost) along with `DOCKER_TLS_VERIFY=1` and `DOCKER_CERT_PATH=<path>`
4. I set DOCKER_OPTS in /etc/default/docker to `"--tlsverify --tlscacert=<path>/ca.pem --tlscert=<path>/server-cert.pem --tlskey=<path>/server-key.pem -H=0.0.0.0:2376"`

`gcloud preview app setup-managed-vms` works now, but I haven't gotten `gcloud preview app run` for my go app to work yet.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26823017 was mentioned that Docker 1.3.2 should solve the problem Docker 1.3.1 had

Comment: Did you have to do anything with permissions? I have to run all my cli commands with sudo and I expect the gcloud client may be having issues in that regard as well.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is gonna help, but you could try with a more explicit DOCKER_HOST:

```
DOCKER_HOST=tcp://localhost:2376
```

Answer (score 0):

I installed Docker 1.3.2 from `unstable` (Debian), added

```
DOCKER_OPTS="-d -H fd:// -H tcp://localhost:2375"
```

to `/etc/default/docker`, and set

```
DOCKER_HOST=tcp://localhost:2375
```

to make it work.

This site contains information how to configure default Docker settings for CoreOS (systemd)
https://coreos.com/docs/launching-containers/building/customizing-docker/