# gcloud deploy issue - boot2docker 1.3.1

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine, boot2docker, gcloud

This is a follow on from the question here:

[gcloud deploy error: Image with tag google/docker-registry was not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26823017/gcloud-deploy-error-image-with-tag-google-docker-registry-was-not-found/26832581#26832581) which is based on the post here http://www.incrediblemolk.com/running-node-js-on-google-app-engine-managed-vms/ .

I've followed the steps in the second link and succeeded in getting gcloud and docker to run the github project https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/appengine-nodejs-quickstart locally.  However I am stuck on deployment.

After downloading the docker-registry container, I found that I had the 'insecure registry' issue, so I followed the steps in the top rated answer in the stack overflow question linked above. However when I tried to restart the daemon, I received a 'Tls message' as follows:

`docker@boot2docker:/mnt/sda1/var/lib/boot2docker$ sudo /etc/init.d/docker restart 
Need TLS certs for boot2docker,127.0.0.1,10.0.2.15,192.168.59.103`

I was wondering if there is something that I need to do, or if this is a boot2docker issue?  I noticed that in the boot2docker project on github, people mentioned 'workarounds' for disabling tls, which I managed to do by adding a line

DOCKER_TLS=no

to my /var/lib/boot2docker/profile file within the VM, and this did enable me to restart the docker daemon, however "gcloud preview app deploy --server preview.appengine.google.com ." requires that tls is enabled.  So I feel like I'm untying one hand from behind my back and replacing it with the other in this instance!

Is there some fix required for this, or am I missing something important?   If so, do I need to use boot2docker 1.3.0 as opposed to 1.3.1?

If anyone could help me in this matter that would be greatly appreciated.

Otherwise, my strategy I think would be to wait for these tools to mature a bit more, as I am after all using the preview version of gcloud, and I think TLS support in boot2docker is relatively new.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, 1.3.1 is not compatible with our SDK. Plese use the latest (as of today) 1.3.2 or 1.3.0.

Comment: I am using Boot2Docker 1.3.2, still I see this message.