# Build Error while deploying to App Engine using custom containers

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine, docker

I am using a nodejs based custom deployment on App Engine using google/nodejs-runtime docker image.

I built my code on the localhost via

```
gcloud preview app run .
```

and it runs fine. But when i deploy it to my App Engine using

```
gcloud preview app deploy .
```

it give this error (along with whole stacktrace):

```
Build Error: Get https://index.docker.io/v1/repositories/google/nodejs-runtime/images: dial tcp: lookup index.docker.io on 192.168.2.1:53: no answer from server.
```

This seems to be error while fetching the repository from the internal google repos. Is it?

- If yes, why is this and how can i make sure that this doesn't happen 
  again.
- If no, then what is it and how do i solve it?

Comment: NOTE: This error occurred while deploying today, while the same code has been deploying and serving perfectly yesterday.

Comment: I think you've just got caught out by some downtime at the Hub, try again now.

Comment: The error message looks like a local DNS issue. Is your DNS resolver running on 192.168.2.1? Can you successfully resolve hostnames using this resolver: host index.docker.io 192.168.2.1. This previous docker issue suggests that restarting boot2docker may help to fix issues where your resolver recently changed: https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/3603

Answer (score 0):

So this is what happens while deploying to the app engine:

- Docker check for Google's repo for the image, as the image file i am using (google/nodejs-runtime) is by google and hosted on Google as well (i guess).
- Check for any updates to the docker image and update the image file, this is necessary to always push updated versions to the deployment.
- Pull changes and push the image to App Engine server and check if the app is serving.

While my assumption was that the issue was in docker registry on Google's end, it was not so.

So there were actually two issues which were causing the issue:

Primary issue (as mentioned in question's comments by @John-Lowry):
It was of the error was DNS name resolution to connect to the docker servers. This was due to my ISP's DNS issue which was blocking access to the servers. Resolved when changed ISP and also resolved after some time on the ISP #1.

Secondary issue (Not sure if exactly related):
Once i switched ISP the following error occurred

```
google.appengine.tools.docker.containers.ImageError: Image with tag google/docker-registry was not found
```

This was resolved once i updated the image from the server. [Similar Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26823017/gcloud-deploy-error-image-with-tag-google-docker-registry-was-not-found) And finally the updated app was pushed to the servers.

I am not sure why the error occurred, but this is what i assessed:

The docker registry image (google/docker-registry) was updated at some point before the deployment. While deployment, the checks were performed for the image in use (google/nodejs-runtime) but since nodejs-runtime is dependent on docker-registry (i am guessing for maintaining various access policies), it was necessary to update to the newer image.

Please suggest edits.